# VBA 'Datatype Mismatch in query expression' when querying SharePoint List

Tags: sql, excel, vba, sharepoint-2010

I am able to successfully query my sharepoint list using VBA. However, I get a datatype mismatch error when adding a date condition.
I am trying to query all dates that are greater than or equal to the current year.

The sharepoint list has a date column and formatted as "short date" and the VBA code is below.

Appreciate someone helping me with the correct syntax.

I have tried the following queries that don't work:

```
'r = DateSerial(Year(Date), 1, 1)
sSQL = "SELECT [fullname] FROM [listname] WHERE [Holiday Date] >= '" & Format(DateValue(r), "m/d/yyy") & "'"

sSQL = "SELECT [fullname] FROM [listname] WHERE [Holiday Date] >= '" & DateValue("1/1/2019")") & "'"

sSQL = "SELECT [fullname] FROM [listname] WHERE [Holiday Date] >= '" & DateSerial(Year(Date), 1, 1) & "'"
```

Comment: give a try to this ... sSQL = "SELECT [fullname] FROM [listname] WHERE [Holiday Date]>= '1/1/2019'"

Comment: @KubaDo nope! that didn't work too :(

Comment: can You simply, select one record, and paste here Your datetime format ?

Comment: when I query one record, I get the date returned in my cell in this format "m/d/yyyy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :)

```
sSQL = "SELECT [fullname] FROM [listname] WHERE [Holiday Date] >="&"1/1/"& Year(Now);
```

Comment: I get an undefined function on 'convert' lol. I truly appreciate your time and effort in trying to assist me

Comment: Alright,, with you pointing me in the right direction, I managed to get it to work with this statement:

Comment: where [holiday date] >= CDate('1/1/2019"

Comment: However, the whole point was also to ensure this is dynamic so I was looking to pick up the start date of the current year. I tried the working sql and back to the original error. Any ideas?

Comment: >= CDate('DateSerial(Year(Date), 1, 1)')"

Comment: You wrote that format is "m/d/yyyy" so meaby : CDate('DateSerial(1,1,Year(Date))')"

Comment: Yikes, that didn't work :(. shucks I am so desperate!

Comment: >= CDate("1/1/"& Year(Now))        - try this

Comment: I see it as "M/d/yyyy" under regional and language settings. Is there a way I can format the CDate to this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198246/discussion-between-marv-and-kuba-do).